# Selenium how to inspect application tab and look at local storage

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was wondering if it would be possible to execute the following instructions in a selenium webdriver

Basically what I'm trying to do is the following:

1. Press Ctrl+Shift+M (⇧⌘M) to toggle device toolbar
2. Navigate to the Application tab
3. On the left, expand Local Storage and select https꞉//discord.com
4. Type Token into the Filter box

So as an example, I attached a screenshot of what it looks like in a selenium browser

[image]

Edit: I'm not trying to follow the exact step, but I'm just trying to get the value corresponding the the `token` key in the image below.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that your scenario is possible to execute with your exact steps. There is a reason why [CDP and BiDi API was introduced in Selenium 4](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidirectional/chrome_devtools/).

You can use JavaScript to set item in the localstorage:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)webDriver;
js.ExecuteScript("localStorage.setItem('token','123');");
```

For Python use:
`browser.execute_script("localStorage.setItem('token','123');")`

For getting the token value:
`browser.execute_script("localStorage.getItem('token');")`

Reference:
[Setting LocalStorage with Chrome and Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68378877/setting-localstorage-with-chrome-and-selenium)
[What does execute_script() in Selenium does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64987951/what-does-execute-script-in-selenium-does)
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_storage_getitem.asp

Comment: Hmm Is it possible to get the value corresponding to the Token key then ? I'm not looking to follow the exact steps but just trying to get the value of the token key.

Comment: Yes, you can localStorage.getItem(keyname)
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_storage_getitem.asp
I updated my answer